# When using a array and `urlencoding` it with `urllib.urlencode()` it shows an error

Tags: python, urllib, urlencode

When I am using `urllib` and `urllib2` to access the web like `news.google.com` and try to put some get request using:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
data = {}
data['output'] = 'rss'
data['num'] = 1
url_val = urllib.urlencode(data)
url = 'https://news.google.com/'
ful_url = url + '?' + url_val
data_rec = urllib2.urlopen(ful_url)
print(data_rec)
```

It shows an error like: `<addinfourl at 43609384 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x02989A30>>`

But When I am using something like

```
import urllib2
import urllib
url = "news.google.com/?output=rss&num=1"
data_rec = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print(data_rec)
```

It works! But why does the first method not work?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example actually gives the same result as your first one. The result is not an error, but simply a string representation of an urllib connection.

To print the contents of the resource, you need to read data from the connection:

```
print(data_rec.read())
```